# Aspnetcore httpcontext session gets null

Tags: asp.net-core

My httpcontext.session  gets null when i use atom payment gateway with my testing login credentials and 
i got session null when return from payment gateway of atom.

Please tell me how session can null?

Comment: Show some code and show how you know something is null.

Comment: After return from gateway then it comes to my return url and i check all session gets null

Comment: Details should be in the body of the question, not comments. Comments can be deleted.

Comment: Ok mr. Jdv i will show code tomorrow

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you understood my question??

Comment: Have you taken the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read the basic How to Ask document?

Comment: I will get learn next time but have you understood my question??

Comment: You should clearly state what you are trying to do, what you tried, and what results you got. Without any code or a description of what you tried no one can understand exactly what you want. It is your responsibility to craft as clear and complete question as you can.

Comment: Dear sorry for that now but i will remember this next time and i will share detail of problem with code and thanx Jdv for this

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `services.AddSession();` to your startup class to configure your middleware.